# ошибка в логическом выражении

Tags: c++, arduino

```
#include <Time.h>  
#include <Wire.h>  
#include <DS1307RTC.h>

const int RELAY_PIN = 4;

void alarm()
{
  Serial.println("alarm!!!");
  digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, HIGH);
  delay(3000);
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(RELAY_PIN, OUTPUT);
  TimeElements t;
  time_t timeValue = makeTime(t);
  RTC.set(timeValue); // прошиваем время в модуль
  setTime(timeValue); // устанавливаем локальное время (из модуля)
}

void loop()
{

  if (((hour() == 8) && (minute() == 0)) || ((hour() == 8) && (minute() == 55)) || ((hour() == 9) && (minute == 0)) || ((hour() == 9) && (minute() == 45)) || ((hour() == 9) && (minute() == 50)) || ((hour() == 10) && (minute() == 35)))
  {
    alarm();  
  }

  digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW);
  Serial.println(second());
  delay(1000);
}
```

В блоке `if` ошибка, но я не могу ее найти. Вот текст ошибки:

> ```
> sketch_oct11a:27: error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' 
> and 'int' to binary 'operator==' exit status 1 invalid operands of types 
> '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator=='
> ```

Comment: И? В чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: в блоке if ошибка, но я не могу ее найти .вот текст ошибки : sketch_oct11a:27: error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator=='

exit status 1
invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator=='

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы не путаться в операторах - разделяйте длинную строку группами в столбик, и тогда сразу увидите где у вас ошибка.

```
if (   ((hour() == 8) && (minute() == 0)) 
    || ((hour() == 8) && (minute() == 55)) 
    || ((hour() == 9) && (minute == 0))    // <-- В этой строчке ошибка
    || ((hour() == 9) && (minute() == 45)) 
    || ((hour() == 9) && (minute() == 50)) 
    || ((hour() == 10) && (minute() == 35))
)
```

Comment: спасибо дядя ты просто БОГ!!! ты открыл мне глаза!!!

Comment: Хорошее оформление кода - это одно из основных чему нужно учиться при программировании.